# What exactly do all of Shulk's different modes do?

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

When playing as Shulk, if you use B, you cycle through 5 different modes called Jump, Speed, Shield, Buster, and Smash. Whichever one you end on seems to give you some kind of buff for a while. Some are clear what the buff is, but others aren't. What exactly do each of these buffs do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Neutral Special: Shulk activates one of five arts, which display kanji characters behind him when selected, to enhance some of his abilities while reducing others. The arts are:

翔 (Jump): Higher jumps, lower defense.

疾 (Speed): Faster movement, lower jumps, weaker attacks.

盾 (Shield): Higher defense, lower jumps, weaker attacks, slower movement.

斬 (Buster): Stronger attacks, weaker launch ability, lower defense.

撃 (Smash): Stronger launch ability, weaker attacks, lower defense against launching.

Custom 1    Decisive Monado Arts    —   Arts last longer, but once an Art is activated it cannot be changed.

Custom 2    Hyper Monado Arts   —   Both positive and negative effects of Arts are amplified, and the Arts last for a shorter duration of time.

***[SOURCE](http://www.ssbwiki.com/Shulk_%28SSB4%29)***